# What is the pathway for the nerve to the Levator ani muscle?

Tags: neuroscience

It seems that the nerve of the Levator ani muscle related to the pundendal nerve, but does it take the same path?

The pudendal nerve starts from s2, s3, s4, it passes near the piriformis muscle (sometimes above and sometimes below it), then near the coccygeus (ischiococcygeus) muscles and leaves the pelvis through the lower part of the greater sciatic foramen, It crosses over the lateral part of the sacrospinous ligament and reenters the pelvis through the lesser sciatic foramen. After reentering the pelvis, it accompanies the internal pudendal artery and internal pudendal vein upwards and forwards along the lateral wall of the ischiorectal fossa, being contained in a sheath of the obturator fascia termed the pudendal canal.

The levator ani start from s3, s4 only, but what is its pathway? what muscles does it cross? with any variations?